# Invalid column name 'LanguageID' in Nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I want to install [Nopcommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/) in local host. When I open it in visual studio and run, I fill in install page like this:

[image]

When I click on install button, after seconds this error message has been shown:

> Setup failed: Invalid column name 'LanguageID'.

Of course it's database is created and has been shown in my list of databases in ssms, but if I run again, I redirect to install page!

> Note:My sql server collation is set to `Persian_100_Bin`

I am using sql server 2014 and nopcommerce 3.8

How can I sovled this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. 
There are some errors due to the fact that MS SQL Server Collation is case sensitive. You can take the help as described in this [forum post](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/44817/ms-sql-server-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1254_cs_as.aspx). All you need is to correct the names of some fields in two SQL queries.